# transform.position not working properly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity and i want to get the position of the player ( witch is a prefab ) so i use the code for the enemy:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;

    void Start() 
    {
        Debug.Log(player.position.x);
    }

}
```

I have a spawner and here is the code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnEnemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemy;
    float randX;
    float randY;
    Vector2 whereToSpawn;
    public float spawnRate = 2f;
    float nextSpawn = 0.0f; 


    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            randX = Random.Range(-6.36f, 6.36f);
            randY = Random.Range(-4.99f, 4.99f);
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, randY);
            Instantiate (enemy, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run it, it always gives me (0, 0, 0). Why do i get 0 and how can i fix it ( get the current position of the player )?

Comment: if its initial position is 0,0,0, you'll always have  this value,... if you want to change its initial value do in Start()  .player.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,z)  what you want for x,y,z or i miss something...

Comment: Do you know what is unity monobehavior life cycle ? 
watch this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```cs
Vector3 position = transform.position;
debug.log(position.x);
```

you can see more here [Transform.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html)

Comment: It gives me `'Vector3' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

Comment: ´´´
Vector3 position =transform.position;
debug.log(position.x);`
´´´
Try removing the new vector3

Answer (score 0):

You Debug.Log() the transform.position only once at the very start when the scene is loaded. Is it possible your object always starts there at 0,0,0 and then moves? If this is the case you are printing it's start position but never updating it. Try printing it on a key press of just every frame by putting it in Update(){}.

If that doesn't work, perhaps your object is nested within another? If so could help narrow down your issue by debug logging both `transform.position` *and* `transform.localPosition`?

Comment: I use a enemy spawner, so it spawns in every 2 seconds

Comment: @Nobert yes but is the enemy spawner located at the position (0,0,0)? If so, the prefab will be spawned at (0,0,0), assuming you use the spawner location as the point to instantiate the prefab. If they are spawned at (0,0,0), on Start() they will log their position once while they are at the 0 point. Sorry if none of this is relevant. I'm just looking for clarification.

Comment: The spawner spawns the enemies in random positions

Comment: ```transform.localPosition``` works for me...